Gronwall inequality for a different power
If
$$ u'(t) \leq a_1\,u(t) + a_0 \,, $$
the Gronwall lemma guarantees that
$$u(t)\leq\, u(0)\,e^{a_1 t} + \frac{a_0}{a_1}\, (e^{a_1t}-1) \,.$$
What if we have something like
$$u'(t) \leq a_1 u^k(t) + a_0$$
for some power $k$?
I see that this question asks this question for the case $k=2$ and uses a change of variables that brings $k$ back to $1$. But I can't think of a general formula for this change of variables.

You can use the following result on differential inequalities: Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be locally Lipschitz continuous and let $u:[0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $u'(t) \le f(u(t))$. If $v:[0, \omega_+) \to \mathbb{R}$ is the solution of the IVP $v'=f(v)$, $v(0)=u(0)$ (nonextendable to the right) then $u(t) \le v(t)$ for $0 \le t < \min{T,\omega_+}$.

@Gerd thank you! I posted an answer based on your comment for my own reference. Does it look right to you? I don't think I understand the time-bound -- why not just let $v$ be defined on $[0,T)$ as well?

I think your solution to $v'=a_1v^k$ is not correct. For example for $k=2$ the solution of the IVP $v'=a_1v^2$ , $v(0)=c>0$ is $v(t)=\frac{1}{1/c-a_1t}$. If also $a_1 > 0$ this solution has a blowup at $\omega_+=1/(ca_1)$. That's the reason that you cannot assume that $v$ is defined on on the same domain as $u$.

If $u'(t) \leq a_1 u^k(t)$, then $u(t) \leq v(t)$ where $v$ satisfies
$$v'(t) = a_1 v^k(t) \,,$$
which has the solution
$$v(t) = \frac{1}{p+1} v^{k+1}(t) + v(0)\,.$$
Suppose that $v(0) = u(0)$. We have
$$ u(t) \leq \frac{1}{p+1} u^{k+1}(t) + u(0) \,. $$
This question/answer gives a proof of the general case $u'(t) = f(u(t))$.
